# How to get the json data by yii2

Tags: angularjs, json, yii2

Two question:
1.I use the post method of yii2 to get the json data, sent by front end with ngResource in Angularjs. And I configure the yii2 as follow:

```
'parsers' => [
    'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    'text/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
 ]
```

But it doesn't work when I use $post = Yii::$app->request->post() to get the data. Additionally, the data is not serialized.
2.I configure the yii2

```
'response' => [
        'formatters' => [
            \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter',
                'prettyPrint' => YII_DEBUG,
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

When I find that it is different from

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
```

before return some value. The former doesn't transform the data to json format. I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

1.I force the contentTye to application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8, it is so silly.
2.Formatters is different from format.